# Fast zoom in and out in Unity Editor

Tags: unity, scene, view, ide

Is it possible to zoom out and zoom in in Unity Editor in Scene View faster than just with the help of scroll wheel on the mouse? I hope there are exist some shortcut for that. Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is double-click the object you wish to get close to, in the `Hierarchy` view. This will rapidly advance the camera to that object's position. You can then use mouse wheel to adjust zoom.

Other than this, I don't believe there is anything like hotkey-assigned zoom levels, unfortunately.

Comment: You can also press **F**, from the scene window. Unfortunetly, in my experience, "framing" is not very reliable, in Unity. It might focus frame on the object. It might zoom right out so you have *significantly more* distance to zoom in.

Answer (score 7):

In `Scene` view.

For Windows:

1. To enter fast zoom mode hold `Alt` + move mouse holding `Right Mouse Button`.
2. Press `F` to **Focus** on `Game Object`.
3. Press `Shift` + `F` to **Focus** on `Game Object` and follow it automatically.
4. Hold `Right Mouse Button` and move with `WASD` - the more time you spend doing it the faster speed of movement you will get.

Note, that the more you zoom you might notice that zoom slowed down. To better address this problem first do `2-nd` step and then try `1-st` one.

For Mac:

It should be the same.

---

*In future releases of Unity we will have ability to set up our own short-cuts with a nice graphical interface.*

Comment: F Key worked . Thank you.
checked on 2018.3.0f2

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me using version 2020: 
Pressing the `F` key on a terrain object reset the mouse sensitivity.

Answer (score 1):

Holding `Right Mouse Button` button and scrolling the `scroll wheel` will let you adjust the `WASD` speed.

Answer (score 0):

To *zoom out* quickly, you can double click an object on the scene hierarchy with no (sprite) renderer attached for example. This will save you from having to use your mouse wheel for  a long time.

To *zoom in* quickly you can double click on the object with (sprite) renderer where you want to zoom in to